# Change the texture every 5 seconds in SparkAR

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I have a particle system, a material and I have 10 different textures to choose from. Is there a way to randomize the texture every 5 seconds for my emitter?

[image: SparkAR]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Loop animation 'Looped' pulse to trigger the random value every time it completes a loop. Floor the random value so it outputs a whole number and then put the output from that into an Option Picker to choose the Texture.

[patch example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAT1L.png)